# Is there a way to group localised resources under same drawables folder and specify sizes inside?

Tags: android, localization, drawable, android-drawable

I'm supporting several languages in my application, as a result I have an image for the splash screen that contains text, that is designed in a very special way (and because of that I can't use a simple `TextView`).

Because of that I had to provide this image for all languages and for all sizes, this results in a very huge and messy **res** folder:

[image]

One thing that I thought about and would be really great if could be done is to group all the images, let's say under **drawable-de** to the same folder and there to specify the size. something like:

**/drawble-de/hdpi**

**/drawble-de/xhdpi**

Does someone knows if this could be done?